What Kind of BLE Handshake is This?
I have a peripheral to which I am trying to connect over BLE. I do not have access to the internals of the peripheral, though I do know it is using a TI CC2540 chip for its BLE implementation (not sure if that matters.) I am having trouble maintaining a connection to the peripheral. It appears to require a handshake/key exchange that must begin within 3 seconds or it auto-disconnects.
I am able to sniff BLE packets between the peripheral and another application (that I don't own) that establishes and maintains a connection. The following are transmissions between the peripheral and the computer for a successful connection.
In the tables, Send is the application sending bytes to the peripheral via a BLE "Write with Response" operation. Recv is when the peripheral responds with a BLE "Handle Value Notification" operation. (In other words, I believe the data is otherwise unencrypted.) The "heartbeat" messages are after the connection has been established - the computer and peripheral send the same two messages back and forth every second thereafter.



Op
Data
Notes




Send
0000 2500 0005 3EA1 B14B 7874 35C2 0000



Recv
0000 0700 0000 E973 EA6F 8104 1421 0000



Send
0000 0E05 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000



Recv
0000 0701 0000 E38C DF6B 65AA 3C22 0000



Send
0000 0E06 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000



Recv
0000 0702 0000 BF03 0174 6327 1AEE 0000



Send
7720 B9B0 A71A ED3D F232 A3AE 1B49 8430



Send
6118 91C4 DD9E 8ACD 91C3 FD82 40F8 A6E8



Send
334F 62B2 E311 B601 9A7E A57A EAC7 AF3C



Recv
DF8E B98F 72FC 8565 440A 3FB1 DD53 2B91



Send
6E17 C496 7F80 91AA 608E 4C63 440D 6BB1



Recv
B113 B032 A034 06B9 3474 7948 FC98 FF5F



Recv
5E86 1021 9DAB BE8B 5B9C BA5B 9672 59EB



Send
D6C6 22C1 007C E473 6045 565F 8D8A FB19



Send
1C04 4FF9 4430 86F9 D3A0 D43A 3DA3 6A72
Heartbeat Send


Recv
EF84 B93A 97B2 B095 0D25 2A90 2DE4 5E69
Heartbeat Recv



Another successful connection example:



Op
Data
Notes




Send
0000 2500 00D1 49B8 4E36 831D 22DF 0000



Recv
0000 0700 0000 D716 3628 6857 0CFE 0000



Send
0000 0E05 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000



Recv
0000 0701 0000 4B63 6017 8AE1 3F08 0000



Send
0000 0E06 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000



Recv
0000 0702 0000 6705 56F6 B46F 0D57 0000



Send
949D 255B 63BC A90E EAA4 3A41 B5E4 1AB7



Send
B0A4 3CE6 E00D EA11 B3EA A0CC 6C6E C9CB



Send
8309 FA93 F327 1E4C E795 A6C4 38AC 3A85



Recv
2133 3FBE DD9C BEC8 84EC F53B 7727 0B5D



Send
AE71 52CE EC30 06B7 2309 16CA A2DE 08DF



Recv
1F7D F64D B14F E54B 0B99 7C71 2C1F 9ADC



Recv
50DC A346 C693 7711 2568 C635 1810 A0A8



Send
7B2F 73DB DCB3 97F0 9C28 535A 252B 05CF



Send
44BF F48B 402D 3470 E2D4 2211 0F31 CBF0
Heartbeat Send


Recv
1A45 9DF7 1931 22C8 8EBB B56D E997 AA94
Heartbeat Recv



Can anyone identify what the handshake is here? I am having a hard time searching for what the protocol is and how I might implement it to successfully connect to the peripheral.

If "Write with Response" command is used the protocol you are talking about is an application level protocol. The term "BLE Handshake" can misunderstood as the BLE pairing also contains a "BLE Handshake". Reversing a protocol, just by looking at the transmitted data is usually very difficult. If there is really no different way record the handshake a few dozen times and then compare them. Identify static parts and changing part and try to guess what the changing parts are.
